# How to remove the sleep button from the login window?

Tags: login-screen

I'm trying to remove the "Sleep" button from the login window on some of my Mac's to prevent inadvertently disabling access to the remote server.

How to disable the sleep button from Mac OS X login screen?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Terminal command:

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SleepDisabled -bool True
```

To re-enable the Sleep button later on, use:

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SleepDisabled -bool False
```